# How do you get a property from a dynamic object when the name is a reserved keyword?

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a `dynamic` object `data` with an property called `data.gold.base`.

If we try this:

```cs
int goldValue = data.gold.base;
```

We get a compilation error, saying that the keyword is not appropriate.

Likewise, if we wanted to get the properties `data.default` or `data.if`, we would get compilation errors.

Is there any way to get these dynamic properties without having to resort to reflection?